# Trouble with Reactive Dataframes in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Here's the [**minimal reproducible example**:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
# This is a Shiny web application. 

library(shiny)

# UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("A Problematic App - Part 2"),
    
    # Sidebar with two slider inputs
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput(
                "NoOfSamples",
                label = "Sample Size",
                value = 100,
                min = 10,
                max = 150,
                step = 10,
                width = "40%"
            ),
            sliderInput(
                "KeepSamples",
                label = "Samples to Keep",
                value = 50,
                min = 10,
                max = 150,
                step = 10,
                width = "40%"
            )
        ),
        
        # Shows the resulting table
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("table1"),
            tableOutput("table2")
        )
    )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # Using the iris dataset
    datExpr <- as.data.frame(iris)
    
    n = reactive({
        input$NoOfSamples
    })
    datExpr0 <- reactive({
        datExpr[1:n(), ]
    })
    output$table1 <- renderTable({
        datExpr0()
    })
    # Displays the first table correctly if the rest is commented out
    keepSamples = reactive({
        input$KeepSamples
    })
    datExpr <- reactive({
        datExpr0()[keepSamples(),]
    })
    output$table2 <- renderTable({
        datExpr()
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have created live examples for demonstration.

- [With the second part of the program commented out](https://kitswas.shinyapps.io/temp/).
- [The complete program](https://kitswas.shinyapps.io/temp2/). [Shinyapps.io] is supressing the error details, so attached is a screenshot of a local run. [image: Screenshot]

The error is `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. While many questions (and answers) regarding this error exist, I am yet to find any explaining the behaviour demonstrated above.

*Why* does this happen?

The normal (script-equivalent) works as expected.

```
datExpr <- as.data.frame(iris)
n = 50
datExpr0 <- datExpr[1:n, ]
datExpr0
keepSamples = 10
datExpr <- datExpr0[keepSamples,]
datExpr
```

Is there a way to achieve what the normal script does in the shiny app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you have both a dataframe and a reactive in your app called `datExpr`. Simply rename one of both (I decided for the reactive).

**EDIT** There is of course nothing special about that in `shiny`.

A simple example to illustrate the issue:

```r
datExpr <- iris
datExpr <- function() {}
datExpr[1:2]
#> Error in datExpr[1:2]: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

And you see that we get the famous `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable error` too.  The general issue or lesson is that in R you can't have two different objects with the same name at the same time.

```r
# This is a Shiny web application. 

library(shiny)

# UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("A Problematic App - Part 2"),
  
  # Sidebar with two slider inputs
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
        "NoOfSamples",
        label = "Sample Size",
        value = 100,
        min = 10,
        max = 150,
        step = 10,
        width = "40%"
      ),
      sliderInput(
        "KeepSamples",
        label = "Samples to Keep",
        value = 50,
        min = 10,
        max = 150,
        step = 10,
        width = "40%"
      )
    ),
    
    # Shows the resulting table
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table1"),
      tableOutput("table2")
    )
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Using the iris dataset
  datExpr <- as.data.frame(iris)
  
  n = reactive({
    input$NoOfSamples
  })
  datExpr0 <- reactive({
    datExpr[1:n(), ]
  })
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    datExpr0()
  })
  # Displays the first table correctly if the rest is commented out
  keepSamples = reactive({
    input$KeepSamples
  })
  datExpr1 <- reactive({
    datExpr0()[keepSamples(),]
  })
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    datExpr1()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3648
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for pointing out the issue and fixing it. 
Could you elaborate why this happens? Is it by design or a bug?

Comment: There is nothing special about that in `shiny`. Try `datExpr <- iris; datExpr <- function() {}; datExpr[1:2]` and you will get the famous `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` error too. The general issue is that in R you can't have two different objects with the same name at the same time.

Comment: Oh, now I see. I forgot that with reactives, the earlier object has to be maintained and cannot be overwritten.